# Document mode changes to 8 after login

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer

I have a weird scenario where the application login page is in document mode 11 as checked in developer mode Emulation tab but as successful login happens the document mode defaults to 8 and hence the page in not render. All are jsp pages build with structs. After searching online I found some suggestions and tried a few like adding to the compatibility view list etc. but still didn't find any useful fix yet. Can any one share any other solution that can help with the same.

Thanks a ton in advance for all your time to take a look and share your expertise.

Comment: As far as I know, IE support is coming to an end, I recommend that you pay more attention to modern browsers such as Chrome and Microsoft Edge. In addition, you can try using Edge IE mode, does it have the same problem? Just refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/ie-mode/) to use devtools in Edge IE mode.

Comment: Hi, rest all browsers are fine. Only IE gives issues its just some organizations have still policies of using IE. We recommend our users to go for other browsers but was just checking if something can be done for those who are affected.

Comment: Are there relevant meta tags in the page <head> to affect the document mode? And as mentioned in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/ie_standards/ms-iedoco/380e2488-f5eb-4457-a07a-0cb1b6e4b4b5), `Browser emulation modes are not document modes. They instruct Internet Explorer about how to select a document mode when a valid <!DOCTYPE> declaration is included.`

Comment: yap  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> and <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text-html">

Comment: There doesn't appear to be such a meta tag to affect it. You can also test in Edge IE mode to see if the same problem exists. If possible, could your share the website url or provide the html code so that we can reproduce this issue?